# How to in JavaScript or ExtJS: obj['a.b.c'] = 123 => obj.a.b.c = 123?

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I need to convert an object with cannonical properties into object with nested properties, splited by '.'

**Example:**
From:

```
obj['a.b.c'] = 123;
```

to:

```
obj.a.b.c = 123;
```

Any elegant solutions?

Or maybe there is a solution in ExtJS to make `form.getValues()` to return an array of fields grouped by names like `fieldname[1]` or `fieldname.1`?

Comment: So you have a string that has `a.b.c` that you want to use as a object property lookup, or does your code currently assigns properties like `obj['a.b.c']`, but you want to assign properties with `obj.a.b.c`?  I'm extremely confused.

Comment: @Quentin I was just looking for that very same question, as I remember writing the accepted answer for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the private method in ClassManager "createNamespaces". It's essentially what you need to do, except root shouldn't default to global, it should default to your object:

```
function setValue(o, key, value) {
    var root = o,
        parts = key.split('.'),
        ln = parts.length,
        part, i;

    for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
        part = parts[i];

        if (typeof part != 'string') {
            root = part;
        } else {
            if (!root[part]) { 
                root[part] = (i === ln - 1) ? value : {};
            }

            root = root[part];
        }
    }
}

var o = {};
setValue(o, 'a.b.c', 123);
console.log(o.a.b.c);
```